Unable to locate package php8.3
I am trying to upgrade from PHP 7.2 to PHP 8.3 on a Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS server. I am following so many tutorials that indicate the same steps:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.3

But this does not work. I get this message:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.3'

And when I ran the update, I saw these messages that I guess could be related:
Ign:5 https://packages.sury.org/php bionic InRelease
Err:6 https://packages.sury.org/php bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 212.102.46.118 443]

E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

How could I fix it?
